# Как реализовать цикл с определенным временем существования итерации ?

Tags: javascript

Нужен цикл с количеством итераций 5, каждая итерация должна длиться 15 секунд, помогите пожалуйста реализовать на чистом JS

Answer (score 2):

Определение, что такое "существование итерации", пусть останется на совести автора вопроса.

```js
function iteration(left) {
  console.log("steps left: ", left);
  // do something
  if (--left > 0)
    setTimeout(iteration, 500/*change this to 15000*/, left);
}

iteration(5);
```

Comment: технически, итерация не существует 15 секунд, а вызывается каждые 15 секунд. Для более точной реализации, наверное, используя Ваш каркас, необходимо привязаться к текущему времени и в цикле ждать истечения 15 секунд. Не?

Comment: @Дмытрык кхм, кхм, подвесить браузер на 15 секунд? И так пять раз.

Comment: @Дмытрык Или Вы имели в виду точность 15-секундного интервала?

Comment: Нет, я о точности реализации ТЗ. Но Вы верно уточнили, что это подвесит браузер.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю более извращенный способ сетуя на eventLoop:

```js
let i = 0;
//чтобы не ждать долго поставил 500, вам же нужно вписать 15000(в мс)
let loop = setInterval(function(){
    i++;
  console.log('now iteration is ' + i);
}, 500);

//обернуто в setTimeout поскольку интервал асинхронен, оба будут помещены в эвент луп и вызваны в свое время. Если нужно для 5 по 15 секунд то вместо 3000 - пишите 75000.
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(loop);
}, 2500);
```

Comment: "более извращенный" +1