# Как ограничить вызов функции в цикле, ровно 1 раз за итерацию?

Tags: javascript

Есть цикл с 5 итерациями, каждая длиться по 15 секунд, в цикл помещена функция, задача, ограничить вызов функции на каждой итерации. Проловал установление флага, но тогда функция вызывается 1 раз вообще.

Comment: код покажите. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: непонятный вопрос, пожалуйста подробнее.

Comment: *Пробовал установление флага, но тогда функция вызывается 1 раз вообще.* Попробуй сбрасывать флаг в начале цикла, проверять непосредственно перед вызовом функции (или в начале функции) и устанавливать сразу после вызова (или соответственно в конце функции). Просто обязано помочь...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы, кажется, забыли отметить один из данных Вам ответов ([Как реализовать цикл с определенным временем существования итерации ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850339)) как принятый - знак "галочка" слева от ответа.

```js
var flagRunning = false;
function iteration(left) {
  if (flagRunning) {
    console.log("Cannot run - already running.");
    return;
  }
  flagRunning = true;
  console.log("steps left: ", left);
  // do something useful
  if (--left > 0) {
    setTimeout(function(aLeft) {
      flagRunning = false;
      iteration(aLeft);
    }, 1500/*change this to 15000*/, left);
  } else {
    flagRunning = false;
    console.log("Can run again.");
  }
}

iteration(5);
```

```html
<button onclick="iteration(5)">Click</button>
```

Comment: не работает флаг

Comment: @АлексейСмолыгин Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в ответе.

Comment: Можно ли связаться с вами лично, для полного объяснения моей проблемы?