# Цикл для игры на JS

Tags: javascript

Есть функция:

```
var isCall = false;
var fnClick = function(){
    canvas.onclick = function(event){
    if (isCall) {
        return false;
    }

    isCall = true;
        var x = event.offsetX==undefined ?event.layerX:event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY==undefined ?event.layerY:event.offsetY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fill();

     console.log(x +'x'+ y);

        if (ctx.isPointInPath(p1, x, y)) {
            //Множитель очков ТУТ 
            document.getElementById('points').innerHTML = player.points + 5;


        }else {
            alert('lose');


        }

    };
};
```

Нужно добавить цикл состоящий из 5 итераций, длительностью в 15 секунд каждая, при не выполнении условия (ctx.isPointInPath(p1, x, y), цикл должен прекращаться, а при выполнении данного условия продолжать работу, так же данная функция должна вызываться строго 1 раз за итерацию (Я это попытался реализовать установив флаг, но функция ограничивается 1 разом при всем выполнении кода)

Comment: Дк не удивительно, isCall обратно в false то нигде не ставится

Comment: А где именно его нужно ставить обратно не подскажите?

Comment: Если итерация - это то, что происходит внутри обработчика клика, тогда в конце этого обработчика ставьте isCall = false;

Comment: Можно с тобой как то связаться для объяснения проблемы, подробнее ?

Comment: Вы издеваетесь? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850339 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850429 - Вы собираетесь задавать один и тот же вопрос, не объясняя, чем Вас не устраивают ответы, которые Вам дали?

Comment: @Igor Я же написал, что ваш код работает не так как требуется, функция не ограничивается

Comment: @Алексей Мой код делает точно то, что написано в вопросе.

Comment: @Igor Я предоставил функцию которая вызывается в вашем цикле, она даже без флагов isCall не ограничивается

Comment: @Алексей Вы разобрались в том, что делает код в моем ответе?

Comment: Я вставил в ваш код, туда куда нужно вызов моей функции, и он работает не корректно, скорее всего я чего не до понял, помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Comment: @Алексей Вызов какой функции и куда Вы вставили? Если речь идет о функции в этом вопросе, то она процентов на сорок состоит из чепухи.

Comment: @Алексей Обратите внимание, что я отвечал Вам кодом, оформленным в рабочий пример, который Вы имеете возможность запустить. На этом сайте редактор вопросов и ответов содержит прекрасный инструмент для создания работающих примеров html/cs/javascript.

Comment: @Igor можете по подробнее объяснить почему функция в данном примере чепуха?

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо. Давайте разбираться.

Начнем с первой строчки. Вы говорите, что эта функция (`fnClick`?)  многократно вызывается. Эти многократные вызовы - бессмыслены. Все, что делает функция `fnClick`, это назначает обработчик `canvas.onclick`:

```
var fnClick = function(){
  canvas.onclick = function(event){
    ...
  };
};
```

Причем присваивает она этому обработчику все время одно и то же. То есть польза есть только от одного - самого первого - вызова `fnClick`.

До сих пор все понятно?

Comment: да, понятно, продолжайте